# Why is Sturm-Liouville operator closed on $L_2(a,b)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The Sturm-Liouville operator on $L^2_w(a,b)$ is given by $$ Ah=\frac{1}{w}\left(-\frac{d}{dx}\left(p\frac{dh}{dx}\right)+qh\right)$$
Where $w(x),p(x),p'(x),q(x)$  are real-valued, continuous functions on $[a,b],p>0,w>0 $.
And we define the domain of $A$ as follows:$$
D(A)=\left\{{h\in L^2_w(a,b):h,h'\ \text{are absolutely continuous, } h''\in L_2(a,b)\ }\\
\text{and }P_1h=a_1h(a)+b_1h'(a)=0,P_2h=a_2h(b)+b_2h'(b)=0\right\}$$The inner product on $L^2_w(a,b)$ is 
$$\langle h_1,h_2\rangle=\int_{a}^{b}h_1(x)\overline{h_2(x)}w(x)dx.$$ How to prove that $A$ is a closed operator on $L^2_w(a,b)$?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to write an inner product involving $w(x)$?

Comment: $A$ is selfadjoint with respect to the weighted space $L^2_w(a,b)$, which can be proved by showing that $A$ is symmetric on its domain and $A\pm iI$ are surjective.

Comment: Thank you @TrialAndError ! Yes, the inner product should include $w(x)$. Showing that $A$ is self-adjoint  is much more easy. Thanks for reminding me of the fact that the closedness follows directly  from  self-adjointness.